# Web Chat did not display the result

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Currently, I had developed Microsoft Graph ChatBot which retrieves the data from SharePoint but when I debug in Emulator its work, but I deploy in WebChat the result did not display.

**The results from Emulator,**
[image]

**The results from WebChat**
[image]

Anyone know how to solve it or suggestion?

Comment: I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two [versions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/embed#what-is-gemini-scorpio-and-aries) of Web Chat: Gemini and Scorpio. Test in Web Chat is still using the older version - Scorpio - which unfortunately does not support OAuth Cards. The BotFramework Development Team is working to update Test in Web Chat, but if you need an immediate fix, I would recommend creating your own web page that uses the latest version of Web Chat. Take a look at the sample code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>WebChat</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body { height: 100% }
    body { 
      margin: 0;
      }

    #webchat {
      height: 100%;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

  <script>

    (async function() {

      // Note, for the simplicity of this example, we are simply using the Web Chat Secret here;
      // however, it is recommended that you create a backend REST API to generate and manage 
      // tokens for production.

      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: '<WEB_CHAT_SECRET>'}),
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

    })().catch(err => console.log(err));

  </script>
</body>
```

For more examples of how to get started with Web Chat, take a look at the Web Chat [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still not yet display the carousel.

Comment: It’s still not displaying in your own HTML with WevChat v4?

Comment: I'm using RestSharp to retrieve the data from Microsoft Graph, its that the problems of displaying issue ?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue as long as the bot is receiving the data and sending the activity correctly.